# First preceding sibling

Tags: xslt

I am trying to get the first <OBR_ObservationRequest> for every <OBX_Result> node in the following XML. When I use preceding-sibling:: I always get the 2nd <OBR_ObservationRequest> for all the the <OBX_Result> nodes.

I want to extract the preceding OBR_ObservationRequest/OBR_4_UniversalServiceIdent/CE_0_Identifier/text() for each of the OBX_Result node. Please advise.

```
<OBR_ObservationRequest>
        <OBR_1_SetIdObservationRequest>1</OBR_1_SetIdObservationRequest>
        <OBR_2_PlacerOrder>
            <CM_0>M12998577</CM_0>
            <CM_1>MIC</CM_1>
        </OBR_2_PlacerOrder>
        <OBR_3_FillerOrder>
            <CM_0/>
            <CM_1>MIC</CM_1>
        </OBR_3_FillerOrder>
        <OBR_4_UniversalServiceIdent>
            <CE_0_Identifier/>
        </OBR_4_UniversalServiceIdent>
    </OBR_ObservationRequest>
    <OBR_ObservationRequest>
        <OBR_1_SetIdObservationRequest>2</OBR_1_SetIdObservationRequest>
        <OBR_2_PlacerOrder>
            <CM_0>M12998577</CM_0>
            <CM_1>MIC</CM_1>
        </OBR_2_PlacerOrder>
        <OBR_3_FillerOrder>
            <CM_0/>
            <CM_1>MIC</CM_1>
        </OBR_3_FillerOrder>
        <OBR_4_UniversalServiceIdent>
            <CE_0_Identifier>URINEC</CE_0_Identifier>
            <CE_1_Text>URINE CULTURE</CE_1_Text>
            <CE_2_NameOfCodingSystem>L</CE_2_NameOfCodingSystem>
        </OBR_4_UniversalServiceIdent>
        <OBR_5_Priority>R</OBR_5_Priority>
    </OBR_ObservationRequest>
    <OBX_Result>
        <OBX_1_SetIdObservationSimple>1</OBX_1_SetIdObservationSimple>
        <OBX_2_ValueType>TX</OBX_2_ValueType>
        <OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier>
            <CE_0_Identifier>RL</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier>
        <OBX_4_ObservationSubId>
            <CE_0_Identifier>1</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_4_ObservationSubId>
        <OBX_5_ObservationResults>
            <CE_0_Identifier>PRELIMINARY REPORT 01/06/21</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_5_ObservationResults>
        <OBX_6_Units/>
    </OBX_Result>
    <OBX_Result>
        <OBX_1_SetIdObservationSimple>2</OBX_1_SetIdObservationSimple>
        <OBX_2_ValueType>TX</OBX_2_ValueType>
        <OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier>
            <CE_0_Identifier>RL</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier>
        <OBX_4_ObservationSubId>
            <CE_0_Identifier>2</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_4_ObservationSubId>
        <OBX_5_ObservationResults>
            <CE_0_Identifier>ORGANISM 1. ID AND SENSITIVITIES TO FOLLOW.</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_5_ObservationResults>
        <OBX_6_Units/>
    </OBX_Result>
    <OBX_Result>
        <OBX_1_SetIdObservationSimple>3</OBX_1_SetIdObservationSimple>
        <OBX_2_ValueType>TX</OBX_2_ValueType>
        <OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier>
            <CE_0_Identifier>RL</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier>
        <OBX_4_ObservationSubId>
            <CE_0_Identifier>3</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_4_ObservationSubId>
        <OBX_5_ObservationResults>
            <CE_0_Identifier>Saladero,Marie,01/06/21</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_5_ObservationResults>
        <OBX_6_Units/>
    </OBX_Result>
    <OBR_ObservationRequest>
        <OBR_1_SetIdObservationRequest>3</OBR_1_SetIdObservationRequest>
        <OBR_2_PlacerOrder>
            <CM_0>M12998577</CM_0>
            <CM_1>MIC</CM_1>
        </OBR_2_PlacerOrder>
        <OBR_3_FillerOrder>
            <CM_0/>
            <CM_1>MIC</CM_1>
        </OBR_3_FillerOrder>
        <OBR_4_UniversalServiceIdent>
            <CE_0_Identifier>URINEC</CE_0_Identifier>
            <CE_1_Text>URINE CULTURE</CE_1_Text>
            <CE_2_NameOfCodingSystem>L</CE_2_NameOfCodingSystem>
        </OBR_4_UniversalServiceIdent>
        <OBR_5_Priority>R</OBR_5_Priority>
    </OBR_ObservationRequest>
    <OBX_Result>
        <OBX_1_SetIdObservationSimple>1</OBX_1_SetIdObservationSimple>
        <OBX_2_ValueType>TX</OBX_2_ValueType>
        <OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier>
            <CE_0_Identifier>OP1.1</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier>
        <OBX_4_ObservationSubId>
            <CE_0_Identifier>CCC</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_4_ObservationSubId>
        <OBX_5_ObservationResults>
            <CE_0_Identifier>COLONY COUNT:</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_5_ObservationResults>
        <OBX_6_Units>CFU/ML</OBX_6_Units>
    </OBX_Result>
    <OBX_Result>
        <OBX_1_SetIdObservationSimple>2</OBX_1_SetIdObservationSimple>
        <OBX_2_ValueType>TX</OBX_2_ValueType>
        <OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier>
            <CE_0_Identifier>OP1.2</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier>
        <OBX_4_ObservationSubId>
            <CE_0_Identifier>CCC</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_4_ObservationSubId>
        <OBX_5_ObservationResults>
            <CE_0_Identifier>&gt;100,000 CFU/ML</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_5_ObservationResults>
        <OBX_6_Units>CFU/ML</OBX_6_Units>
    </OBX_Result>
    <OBR_ObservationRequest>
        <OBR_1_SetIdObservationRequest>4</OBR_1_SetIdObservationRequest>
        <OBR_2_PlacerOrder>
            <CM_0>M12998577</CM_0>
            <CM_1>MIC</CM_1>
        </OBR_2_PlacerOrder>
        <OBR_3_FillerOrder>
            <CM_0/>
            <CM_1>MIC</CM_1>
        </OBR_3_FillerOrder>
        <OBR_4_UniversalServiceIdent>
            <CE_0_Identifier>NUC61</CE_0_Identifier>
            <CE_1_Text>NEG URINE COMBO 61</CE_1_Text>
            <CE_2_NameOfCodingSystem>L</CE_2_NameOfCodingSystem>
        </OBR_4_UniversalServiceIdent>
        <OBR_5_Priority>R</OBR_5_Priority>
    </OBR_ObservationRequest>
    <OBX_Result>
        <OBX_1_SetIdObservationSimple>1</OBX_1_SetIdObservationSimple>
        <OBX_2_ValueType>ST</OBX_2_ValueType>
        <OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier>
            <CE_0_Identifier>ANT</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier>
        <OBX_4_ObservationSubId>
            <CE_0_Identifier>CAX</CE_0_Identifier>
            <CE_1_Text>CEFTRIAXONE</CE_1_Text>
            <CE_2_NameOfCodingSystem>L</CE_2_NameOfCodingSystem>
        </OBX_4_ObservationSubId>
        <OBX_5_ObservationResults>
            <CE_0_Identifier>&gt;32</CE_0_Identifier>
        </OBX_5_ObservationResults>
        <OBX_6_Units/>
    </OBX_Result>
```

Comment: You get all the preceding siblings. If you want the first, use `preceding-sibling::[1]`.

Comment: Please show the xslt and make more clear in a result example what you expect.